# Do I have to have Sakura Samurai running in order to dedicate steps from the 3DS pedometer to the Rock Garden?

Tags: sakura-samurai

*Sakura Samurai: Art of the Sword* makes uses of the 3DS's pedometer in the Rock Garden activity. According to the manual, I can dedicate my steps to it once a day to improve the garden.

Do I have to have Sakura Samurai running to record the steps or does the game import from the system pedometer the same way the play coins do? Or do I have to run the game, go on a walk, then later launch the game again and go to the Rock Garden then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the confusion stems from the fact the game treats this weirdly the first time you play. It didn't offer to accept my several thousand steps the first time I played, then I went off on the main quest. Later I started the game again and went in to the Rock Garden. It then seems to have zeroed out the previous amount and only registered the 25 steps since the last invocation of the game.

Today I went and after getting some thirteen-hundred steps, started the game and dedicated my steps. Now I have 10% of a cherry tree in bloom. The leaves are very pretty.